# Create array from multiple responses

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter

I have web APIs which can create and delete objects, however, to delete an object I need to use its Id which is generated when I create the object (I get the new object in JSON format as a response).

The URL of the delete method is .../delete/{id}.

My question is how can put this Id into an array (I know how to put this id into a variable using regEx) and then use the values in the array in the URL of the delete method so I could create multiple objects in a row and then delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have an extractor that extracts the id into id variable.
Add after it a [JSR223 Post Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) with following code:

```
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 def id = vars["id"];
 List<String> listIds = (List<String>) vars.getObject("listIds");
 if (listIds == null) {
     listIds = new ArrayList<String>();
     vars.putObject("listIds", listIds);
 }
 listIds.add(id);
```

Then at the place where you want to do the call on array add:

- [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action)

Add to it as a child a [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) with following code:

```
 import java.util.List;
 List<String> listIds = (List<String>) vars.getObject("listIds");
 vars.put("ids_matchNr", listIds.size());
 listIds.eachWithIndex{it,index->
      vars.put("ids_"+(index+1), Integer.toString(it));
 }
```

After the Flow Control Action, add a [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller), with following configuration:

[image]

Comment: Great, one little correction, in the preProcessor the var.put gets a string also for the number, so I needed to convert it.